# Core Image Filtered image jumps out of my UIImageView on iOS 10

Tags: swift, core-image, ios10, cifilter, cikernel

I am having an issue applying certain Core Image Filters on iOS 10. Filters like CICrystallize, CIEdgeWork, CIHexagonalPixellate, CIPointillize jump out of my UIImageView when filter is applied.

Strange part one is the bigger the inputScale the more they shift away from center. Strange part two is that it happens only iOS 10; they were all working fine on iOS 9. Strange part three is that it happens only on real devices; on the iOS 10 simulator all works fine!

Comment: Can you post the minimal code required to reproduce the issue so that we can test it ourselves?

Comment: Thanks HAS. Solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Replaced

```
filteredImage.image = UIImage(CIImage: filteredImageData)
```

With this:

```
let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)
filteredImage.image = UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef!)
```